# Get git log history on Heroku CI dyno

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-ci

I'm running into an issue where I want to get info from `git log` on a Heroku CI dyno, but Heroku doesn't seem to set the folder as a git directory (no `.git` folder.) Is there a way to opt into the dyno being setup with the git data intact?